# How to see the contents of a file with blank filename?

Tags: filesystem, files

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Mar 19 07:30 xxxxx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   580 Mar 20 07:24  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 27137 Mar 20 09:10 xxx.js
```

Here there is a file on the second line but its blank, any idea how to see the contents?

Comment: it's not blank ;) it probably has a unprintable char. Please post results of `ls -b` :)

Comment: ur rite its  a \ - i tot if there is an unprintable char it is higlighted on marking it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inodes to the rescue: first, do `ls -li` to list all files with their inodes. The inode is the number on the left. Note the inode number of your invisible file. Then:`find . -inum xxx -exec nano {} \;` replacing xxx with the inode number, and possibly nano with the editor of your choice.

Explanation:
The find command finds the file with inode number xxx, then executes a command, in this case: passes it to `nano`. The `{}` is a placeholder for the filename; the `\;` at the end indicates the end of the command.

Comment: The find command finds the file with inode number xxx, then executes a command, in this case: passes it to nano. The {} is a placeholder for the filename; the \; at the end indicates the end of the command.

Comment: @Jos Could you edit that into your answer, rather than just a comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a

```
gedit *
```

to open all files (brute force approach)
Or better

```
gedit " "*
```

if you are sure that the file begins with a space character.

(you can replace gedit with your favorite editor)

Comment: nope, didn't work, I used emacs * all the files except this turned up in the buffer.

Comment: What happens if you use `xdg-open *` ? It should open all the files using their default application.

Comment: Its a terminal that I am sshing into.

Comment: `*` will cause shell expansion.  If the file consists of a space character, then `*` will just add whitespace to the commandline.  Therefore, the file will be skipped.